# How to set minimum and maximum number in TextInput in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-textinput

I want to give a min value of 0 and a max value of 100, In between those values user can type, otherwise in between user cannot type. I tried validating the data when the `onTextChanged` events trigger but the UI is re-rendered giving the effect I don't want. I want the same result as when I use the `maxLength` prop. When the user enters 98, I don't allow them to enter more characters (eg: 988) and then validate and reset the old state => 98. I want to check that when the value is 98, the user cannot enter more characters which means `maxLength = 2`.

What's the solution for this issue? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just set state to minimum or maximum when value is not in the required range.

Answer (score 0):

you can use yup to validate text input and show error code